# Sybase Replication server mounted on NAS

Tags: replication, sybase, sybase-rs

To achieve High availability, we are installing Sybase Replication server on NAS drive shared by two servers. We can start and stop Replication server from node1 from where we have installed binaries but cannot start it from other node2 where NAS drive is shared. Howeve, we can access replication server through isql from both the node.

In logs it shows, that embedded sybase database ERSSD is not starting from other node.

Best Regards

Comment: So the ERSSD is located on the NAS?  And both RUN_ files are configured similarly? Can you post some of the errorlog output?  Is this Linux? Unix? Windows? More detail is probably needed to help you out.  You will need the binaries on both systems you plan to run it from, so if it's *nix, you can just copy the files over to the other system.

Comment: Your replication server needs to be able to find its own database on each node. Looks like the node II doesn't see it. Put the database on the NAS.